# Set arbitrary chapter numbers in a PDF of a Quarto book

Tags: quarto

Can I set arbitrary chapter numbers in a PDF of a Quarto book?

I am creating course notes.
I have one chapter per `.qmd` file and bind them into one PDF with the following `_quarto.yml`:

```
book:
  title: FINA 6203
  subtitle: Investment Analysis
  output-file: fina-6203
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - bkm_ch_01.qmd
    - bkm_ch_03.qmd
    - references.qmd
```

I suppress the number on `index.qmd` with `{.unnumbered}` so `bkm_ch_01.qmd` is chapter 1.
Can I force `bkm_ch_03.qmd` to be chapter 3?
I plan to skip a handful of chapters and want to align the notes and textbook chapter numbers.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to suppress chapter and part numbers.
The following snippet in my `_quarto.yml` file suppresses chapter and part numbers:

```
format:
  pdf:
    number-depth: -2
```

Setting `number-depth: -1` suppresses chapter numbers only.